# Can I disable select mode in a PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell

PowerShell default is that when you click inside the PowerShell console, PowerShell goes into "select mode" and pauses the script until you hit space, enter or escape.

I have a Script with an infinite-loop `while ($true) {}` which should always run, how can I tell PowerShell to not stop the script when someone accidentally clicks into the PowerShell window?

Comment: Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30872345/script-commands-to-disable-quick-edit-mode) - it's not an easy fix.

Comment: Does the script have any outputs that you are concerned with? Is having it running with the console not visible an option?

Comment: @Jelphy thanks i'll try.

Comment: @gms0ulman yes the console has to be visible

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In Windows PowerShell, this can be achieved by:

1. Right click on PowerShell window icon;

[image]

2. Select "Properties";
3. Disable "Edit Options" > "QuickEdit Mode".

[image: Powershell Properties]